# exporting csvs in php. issue with filename

Tags: php, csv, http-headers, export

I'm trying to export csvs in php using company names from a database.

I'd like to keep as much of the formatting of a company's name as I can.  Companies like **AutoDesk, Inc.** Are trouble some because of the comma and the period.  Even the space is an issue.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=AutoDesk Inc.csv");
```

In this case (even when I remove comma and period) my filename stops right before the space.  I only get `AutoDesk`

Is there any way to keep my filename intact when exporting a csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"AutoDesk Inc.csv\"");
```

Comment: More readable form
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="AutoDesk Inc.csv"');